# display particular image associated with the listview.

Tags: android, image, listview, onclicklistener

I have a listView of image names.. When i click on the particular image name in listview, the respective image must be displayed. How can i do this? 
My ListView is like this:

ImageName1

ImageName2

ImageName3

....
...

Now when i click ImageName2 : i need to open image associated with ImageName2 in New_Activity.

All this must be performed within this method:

```
private void pathViewClick(ListView lv){

             lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                    i.putExtra("maps","map1.jpeg");
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

             });

     }
```

Comment: open the image in a dialog box or just in the listview?

Comment: no we should open the image in new_activity normally

Comment: Ok, and where are the images coming from? Are they stored in the project or are they coming from a server/some other external source?

Comment: ya the images are in assets folder .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int position = listview.getSelectedItemPosition();
i.putExtra("maps","map"+position+".jpeg");
```

**EDIT 1**

Do this to test if it is retrieving the correct position

```
int position = listview.getSelectedItemPosition();
String pos = Integer.toString(position);
Log.d("Position", pos);
```

This will log the integer it is receiving. Let me know what it says.

**EDIT 2**

```
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

  }
```

The above onItemClick method gives you int position...so try this

```
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
       i.putExtra("maps","map"+position+".jpeg");
       startActivity(i);
       finish();
  }
```

Comment: 07-31 21:09:44.432: I/System.out(474): map-1.jpeg
It doesn't work because if you System.out it prints out above string which is different from the real image name.

Comment: So it is returning -1? I updated the answer for you to test it

Comment: 07-31 21:18:26.482: D/Posi(546): -1
07-31 21:18:26.482: I/System.out(546): map-1.jpeg
07-31 21:18:26.492: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.example.activity.map/.Activity2 (has extras) }
still it is returning -1 idk why !!!

Comment: even with the newer method I just posted? Honestly, I'm not sure why it is returning -1. Try posting your whole code.

Comment: Hey now its working but it works only for second third and soo on but do not work for the first list view item .... overall thanks ..

Comment: Ah...well the first position of the ListView and the position ID on your images may be off. Try doing something like `i.putExtra("maps","map"+position+1+".jpeg");`

Comment: i already tried that before and for this case none of the listview item works

Comment: Hey now everything works well, even for first item. i did was outside position = position + 1 ; thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

get the position from your call

> Object rid = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

If map1 is at position 0 then just add 1 to it eg.
position = position + 1

```
i.putExtra("maps","map" + position + ".jpeg");
```

Comment: can you please explain more about this rid ! how to use it ! i am confused if i randomly click position 5 how does it give me the position !

Comment: Object rid is just the position in the list, if you look at your method handler you can see it returns a view, position and id. So if you click the 1st item the position will return a rid of 0, rid is just what I named the id as I already had and Integer called id, so rid to me means returned - id!

Comment: Object pid = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
     
     i.putExtra("maps","map"+pid+".jpeg"); I used this but it does not work; but if i put the real name of image it works : like ex; map1.jpeg

Comment: whats the value of pid?